# T-SQL cast and converting issues from source tables to destination

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as follows:

```
create table dbo.##Table_A00
(
    RowNo int,
    TRANSACTION_TYPE varchar(3),
    ORGANISATION_ID numeric (10),
    FILE_TYPE varchar(3),
    CREATION_DATE datetime,
    CREATION_TIME varchar(3),
    GENERATION_NUMBER numeric (6)   
)
```

However the source files I am using is a table used to capture flat files and they can be in any data format.

What I have in the source table the data type looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ##Table_Alltextfiles 
(
     rowID int identity (1,1),
     [Col1] varchar(50),
     [Col2] varchar(250),
     [Col3] varchar(50),
     [Col4] varchar(50),
     [Col5] varchar(50),
     [Col6] varchar(50),
     [Col7] varchar(50)
)
```

What I want to do is insert into `##Table_A00` (destination) all rows from  `##Table_Alltextfiles` (source)

However I am having issues doing this as the data type are mis match and I have tried casting it without success.

What can I do to get the value of varchar to its appropiate destination i.e if its a date field or if its a numeric.

This is what I have been tring to do:

```
insert into dbo.##Table_A00
    select 
        rowID, 
        col1, cast(col2 as numeric (10)),
        col3, cast(col4 as date), 
        col5, cast(col6 as numeric (6))
    from 
        ##Table_Alltextfiles
    where 
        col1 = 'A00'
```

Thank you

Comment: you should also post the error information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out with the below query.

```
insert into dbo.##Table_A00
    select 
        rowID, 
        SUBSTRING(col1,1,3), case when ISNUMERIC(col2)=1 THEN cast(col2 as numeric (10)) ELSE NULL END,
        SUBSTRING(col3,1,3), case when ISDATE(col4)=1 THEN  cast(col4 as datetime) ELSE NULL END, 
        SUBSTRING(col5,1,3), case when ISNUMERIC(col6)=1 THEN cast(col6 as numeric (6)) ELSE NULL END
    from 
        ##Table_Alltextfiles
    where 
        col1 = 'A00'
```

Comment: Thank you, your answered work, however what I don't get is the case statement evaluation will always be  equal to 1 (as in its a Numeric or Date respectively) However, should this not work:

Comment: insert into dbo.##Table_A00
    select 
        rowID, 
   SUBSTRING(col1,1,3),
  cast(col2 as numeric (10)),
  SUBSTRING(col3,1,3),
  cast(col4 as datetime),
  SUBSTRING(col5,1,3)
  cast(col6 as numeric (6))
      from 
        ##Table_Alltextfiles
    where 
        col1 = 'A00'

Comment: Just wondering, do you have to account for nulls? is that why it works

Comment: Yes.. The case statement evaluates whether your column returns numeric or date based on the destination column data type and if the value not satisfies will map to null instead.

Comment: I think your date column values is not well formatted.